# PowerBuilder Pipeline does not work in web application?

Tags: powerbuilder, pipeline, sqlanywhere

I'm trying code similar to below to create a data pipeline to migrate data from a database to another.
The pipeline works fine with the desktop application, but when I migrate the application to the .net web forms application to use on the internet, the pipeline does not work. It returns the error code "-1" (while on desktop, it returns 1).
Can someone tell me what is problem, why it does not work on the internet? I am using Powerbuilder classic 12, with Sybase Anywhere 12 using ODBC on Windows XP/IIS 5.1.

```
Transaction trans_source, trans_dest

trans_source=CREATE Transaction
trans_dest=CREATE Transaction

trans_source.DBMS = "ODBC"
trans_source.DBPARM = "ConnectString='DSN=db1;UID=dba;PWD=sql"

trans_dest.DBMS = "ODBC"
trans_dest.DBPARM = "ConnectString='DSN=db2;UID=dba;PWD=sql"

connect using trans_source;
connect using trans_dest;

lp_Create=CREATE p_pipe
lp_Create.DataObject="p_create_tableA"

result_value = lp_Create.Start(trans_source,trans_dest,dw_errors)
messagebox("result", result_value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipelines aren't supported in WebForms. (xref [Deploying Applications and Components to .NET](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00586.1200/html/dplynet/title.htm))

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any alternative way to transfer data from one database to another in the webforms?

Comment: Keep in mind connections are on server side only, so I'm not sure why you'd want/need this in a WebForms app. I'd first look at DBMS-specific solutions (iAnywhere has some good ones; you don't mention which DBMS you're using). If you've got to do it in PB and can't spin it into a separate native app on the server, two DataStores connected to two separate transactions, retrieve into one and copy into the other and update it. I've seen it done generically (querying the column list, querying which columns are key, etc...).